# Using Groups in FMOD and Resonance Audio

Tags: resonance-audio

Does anyone know if there is anyway to use GROUPS in FMOD while using the resonance audio spacialiser plugin?

I've searched everywhere, but documentation seems to be lacking!

EDIT: Forgot to add that it is being used with Unreal Engine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At present the Resonance Audio Plugin is a 'mixing plugin'. All audio routed into a resonance audio source or ambisonic source is mixed internally within the plugin. This allows us to perform spatialization effects *far more efficiently*.

If you have CPU to spare you could consider using more than one ResonanceAudioListener.

Comment: I thought this was the case. Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this makes mixing in Fmod much more complicated. Mixer snapshots rely quite heavily on groups. Do you have any workarounds for this? I did try working  Also, are there any plans to work room effects into the fmod/unreal plugin as in unity?